# How to write an RNN/LSTM custom layer in swift for tensorflow?

Tags: swift, tensorflow, lstm, swift-for-tensorflow

I have a simple tensorflow model with lstm layers. I want to convert the model to .mlmodel format. However, I think, as of now, CoreML does not support LSTM layers and hence I need to write a custom lstm layer in swift.
How can I write that custom layer?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try with Keras and use different tensorflow or other back-ends? the Keras has one of the easiest interfaces.

I suggest reading the tensorflow model using keras. Then use the link below to convert the keras to core-ml.

Try to make it simple. not complicated

https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-coremltools-to-convert-a-keras-model-to-core-ml-for-ios-d4a0894d4aba?gi=76f8b08071e9

Comment: My tensorflow model is a seq2seq model and has got large number of layers and some really basic ops. Is there any way that you can suggest (other than porting the whole code to keras) to convert the model to coreml **.mlmodel** format?

Comment: Keras is like a wrapper for all other packages such as tensorfolow, pytorch etc.  This is the easiest way I can think of. The other method is to manually write to code to transfer. What you ask is not so common. Personally, I tried to convert pytorch model to caffe manually before. It was a disaster. After I get to know keras, I immediately regret my action of manual conversion